# Display name of 'one-hot-encoded' variables for 'feature Importance'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

How can I properly display the name of the 'one-hot-encoded' features after finishing the training and validation of my algorithm? I want to neatly display the name of each feature along with their importance. Below is what I've tried:

**Display feature importance:**

```
grid_search.best_estimator_.feature_importances_
array([  7.67359589e-02,   7.20731884e-02,   4.38667330e-02,
         1.69222269e-02,   1.51816327e-02,   1.66947835e-02,
         1.56858183e-02,   3.43347923e-01,   5.95555727e-02,
         7.65422356e-02,   1.11224727e-01,   1.02677088e-02,
         1.32720377e-01,   1.06447326e-04,   4.45207929e-03,
         4.62258699e-03])
```

**Get one-hot category names:**

```
cat_one_hot_attribs = list(encoder.classes_)
print(cat_one_hot_attribs)
['<1H OCEAN', 'INLAND', 'ISLAND', 'NEAR BAY', 'NEAR OCEAN']
```

**Get rest of names (other categories):**

```
num_attribs = list(X_train)

['longitude',
 'latitude',
 'housing_median_age',
 'total_rooms',
 'total_bedrooms',
 'population',
 'households',
 'median_income',
 'rooms_per_household',
 'bedrooms_per_household',
 'population_per_household',
 0,
 1,
 2,
 3,
 4]
```

**Now I do the following:**

```
attributes = num_attribs + cat_one_hot_attribs

print(pd.DataFrame(sorted(zip(feature_importance, attributes), reverse=True)))
```

**But I get the following:**

```
         0                         1
0   0.343348             median_income
1   0.132720                         1
2   0.111225  population_per_household
3   0.076736                 longitude
4   0.076542    bedrooms_per_household
5   0.072073                  latitude
6   0.059556       rooms_per_household
7   0.043867        housing_median_age
8   0.016922               total_rooms
9   0.016695                population
10  0.015686                households
11  0.015182            total_bedrooms
12  0.010268                         0
13  0.004623                         4
14  0.004452                         3
15  0.000106                         2
```

I have tried other ways as well but all have failed.

Can someone please suggest a way to get this displaying properly? Thank you.

**Edit:**

From @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ 's answer, I tried the following:

```
feature_importance = grid_search.best_estimator_.feature_importances_

cat_one_hot_attribs = list(encoder.classes_)

num_attribs = list(X_train)
attributes = num_attribs + cat_one_hot_attribs

vals = sorted(zip(feature_importance, attributes), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(vals)
print(df)
```

Still getting output as above.

Comment: How do you want it sorted?

Comment: High to low would be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break it down. Sort first, by key. Make sure only the `feature_importance`s are considered.

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

feature_importance = np.array([  7.67359589e-02,   7.20731884e-02,   4.38667330e-02,
     1.69222269e-02,   1.51816327e-02,   1.66947835e-02,
     1.56858183e-02,   3.43347923e-01,   5.95555727e-02,
     7.65422356e-02,   1.11224727e-01,   1.02677088e-02,
     1.32720377e-01,   1.06447326e-04,   4.45207929e-03,
     4.62258699e-03])

cat_one_hot_attribs = ['<1H OCEAN', 'INLAND', 'ISLAND', 'NEAR BAY', 'NEAR OCEAN']

num_attribs = ['longitude',
 'latitude',
 'housing_median_age',
 'total_rooms',
 'total_bedrooms',
 'population',
 'households',
 'median_income',
 'rooms_per_household',
 'bedrooms_per_household',
 'population_per_household',
 0,
 1,
 2,
 3,
 4]

attributes = num_attribs
```

---

Get a sorted list of `vals` by `feature_importance`.

```
vals = sorted(zip(feature_importance, attributes), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(vals)
```

Then, use `.replace` to replace the encodings with the values in `cat_one_hot_attribs`.

```
df.iloc[:, -1] = df.iloc[:, -1].replace({i : k for i, k in enumerate(cat_one_hot_attribs)})
df

           0                         1
0   0.343348             median_income
1   0.132720                    INLAND
2   0.111225  population_per_household
3   0.076736                 longitude
4   0.076542    bedrooms_per_household
5   0.072073                  latitude
6   0.059556       rooms_per_household
7   0.043867        housing_median_age
8   0.016922               total_rooms
9   0.016695                population
10  0.015686                households
11  0.015182            total_bedrooms
12  0.010268                 <1H OCEAN
13  0.004623                NEAR OCEAN
14  0.004452                  NEAR BAY
15  0.000106                    ISLAND
```

Comment: @JohnWayne360 I think you should also do `attributes = cat_one_hot_attribs + num_attribs` before doing this. Can you also please include your expected output? If this didn't solve it, that would help.

Comment: I am, but it's still bugging. Could it be my environment?

Comment: @JohnWayne360 I don't think so. Update your code so I can see what you're doing. Also, some expected output!

Comment: As for the output, it should look like yours. It still looks like the one from my code. I wish i could post the whole code but it is a long file. I'll update with your solution.

Comment: @JohnWayne360 I updated my answer with everything that I'm doing, so you know exactly how I get my output.

Comment: I got it, I needed to switch the order of the sum in 'attributes'. Thanks, you've come to my rescue now x 3!

Comment: @JohnWayne360 Glad to help! Good luck.

Comment: One last question, was I printing the results in the wrong order? Notice how in my post 'median_income' is the most important feature. After applying your answer, 'housing_median_age'. I think this might be wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnWayne360 Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153561/discussion-between-cs-and-johnwayne360).